# Download file from server via Angular 6 and .NET Core

Tags: angular, .net-core

Client(Angular)

```
convertDocument(htmlDoc: string, orderInfo: OrderInfo): Observable<Blob> {
    let convertDocRequestObj = new ConvertDocRequest();
    convertDocRequestObj.fileName = 'SomeUniqueFileName.pdf';
    convertDocRequestObj.page = htmlDoc;
    const url = `${environment.Url}`;
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');  
    return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(convertDocRequestObj),{headers, responseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

API

```
[HttpPost]
 [Route("download")]
 public IActionResult Download([FromBody] ConvertDocRequest request)                             
        {
            try
            {
                var output = _docConverterProxy.ConvertToPdf(request);

                var result = output.Split("~~");

                 return new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(result[0]), "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = result[1] };
                
                

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} -- DocConversion Failed -- Exception Message {exception.Message}");
                return BadRequest(exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly on my local machine. But when i deploy changes to my server, I start getting 500 server error. So, the call from angular never hits the api endpoint. I have tried to invoke the endpoint via postman, results are satisfactory.

Comment: And what does the error says? Could be CORS?

Comment: @iamdlm did doubt that and did add CORS ability to the api, but still the same.

Comment: And what is the exception message?

Comment: 500 Internal server error.. That's it.. Wish i could add a snapshot of the traffic

Comment: I suppose you called the publish API via postman, and with Angular did you checked the endpoint being called?

Comment: Thanks, suggestion helped. I was missing APIKEY.. so silly and the error message so misleading. Solved it finally.